# Strange nginx error, yet nginx -t is fine

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, nginx

When attempting to run `sudo apt install nginx`, I get the very informative error:

`Failed to start a high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.`

When I run `sudo nginx -t`, I get:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Thus I have no idea how to debug or find out what's wrong with my nginx.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log and restart nginx again, and look at the log output.

Maybe you have apache2 already installed ? Port 80 can only be used by one webserver application.

Comment: You're right. It's apache. How can I set nginx to use a different port?

Comment: For Nginx you can let your websites run on a different port by defining a different port than port 80 in the sites-available vhosts configuration files. Note that Nginx has already default vhost configuration on port 80 there, just like Apache has a default one. Make sure to look in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and disable what you do not need.